# How to subtract one list from the other?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have one list like this `{{1, 3}, {2, 5}}` and another like this `{1,2}`, so I want to do first list minus second so that result will be `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many approaches.  These also works.

```
list1 = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}};
list2 = {1, 2};

Transpose@(Transpose@list1 - {{0, 0}, list2})
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}} *)
```

or

```
list1 - Transpose@{{0, 0}, list2}
```

which gives the same answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try `MapThread`

```
list1={{1, 3}, {2, 5}};list2={1,2};
MapThread[#1-{0,#2}&,{list1,list2}]
```

which instantly gives you

```
{{1,2},{2,3}}
```

Study the documentation and see if you can figure out how this works. It takes corresponding pairs of items from each list and does a function to them, in this case doing your subtraction on part of the first list.

If this `&` and `#` stuff is confusing then an equivalent solution that perhaps makes the function more understandable is

```
list1={{1, 3}, {2, 5}};list2={1,2};
f[v1_,v2_]:=v1-{0,v2};
MapThread[f,{list1,list2}]
```

That will do

```
{1,3}-{0,1}=={1,2}
```

and then do

```
{2,5}-{0,2}=={2,3}
```

giving you your desired

```
{{1,2},{2,3}}
```

A completely different way of doing this is to turn your two lists into exactly the same shape and size matricies and then just subtract the two matricies.

```
list1-Map[{0,#}&,list2]
```

which gives you

```
{{1,2},{2,3}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't at first understand the problem statement.  We are subtracting the second list from the second element of the first list.

With that understanding, here is another possibility:

```
Transpose[{list1[[;; , 1]], list1[[;; , -1]] - list2}]
```

This method is using "spans" to pair the first elements of list1 with the second (last) element of list1 minus list2.

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}}; 
l2 = {1, 2};
```

A few additional alternatives:

```
SubsetMap[# - l2 &, l1, {All, 2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}

```
l3 = l1; l3[[All, 2]] -= l2; l3
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}};
b = {1, 2};

a - Thread[{0, b}]
```

{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}};
l2 = {1, 2};
```

Using `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[# - l2 &, Transpose@l1, {2}]

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}*)
```